# DEoptim error: objective function result has different length than parameter matrix due to foreachArgs specification

Tags: r, optimization, deoptimization

I have a very odd `DEoptim` error that I have "fixed", but do not understand.

I do not have issues when I use `DEoptim`'s parallel capabilities with the `parallel` package (i.e., `pType=1`). However when I use `foreach` instead (which I must use on the grid computing setup that is available to me), I have issues. Below is an MRE of a much simplified version of the issue that I had. `pType=1` works, `pType=2` when `foreachArgs` is specified returns an error:

> objective function result has different length than parameter matrix

When I do not specify `foreachArgs` the issue goes away. Does anyone have thoughts about the root cause of this issue?

```
library(zoo)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(DEoptim)


myfunc1 <- function(params){
    s <- myfunc2(params,ncal,n_left_cens,astats, X_ret, disc_length, X_acq, POP_0, POP_ann_growth)
    loss_func(s)
    }

myfunc2 = function(params,ncal,n_left_cens,astats, X_ret, disc_length, X_acq, POP_0, POP_ann_growth){
    sum(params) + ncal + n_left_cens + astats + X_ret + disc_length + X_acq + POP_0 + POP_ann_growth 
    }

loss_func = function(s){
    s
    }   


# General setup
ncal = 1
n_left_cens = 1
astats= 1
disc_length = 1
POP_0 = 1
POP_ann_growth = 1
X_acq = 1
X_ret = 1
params = c(1,1)
W = 1

paral = TRUE
itermax=100
ncores = detectCores()
cltype <- ifelse(.Platform$OS.type != "windows", "FORK", "PSOCK")
trace=TRUE

# bounds for search for DEoptim
lower = rep(-1,length(params))
upper = lower*-1




# parallel: works               
pType = 1
parVar = c("myfunc1","myfunc2","loss_func","W","ncal","n_left_cens","astats","X_ret","disc_length",
                        "X_acq","POP_0","POP_ann_growth")               
foreachArguments <- list("myfunc1","myfunc2","loss_func","ncal","n_left_cens","astats","X_ret","disc_length",
                        "X_acq","POP_0","POP_ann_growth")
clusters <- makeCluster(ncores, type = cltype)
registerDoParallel(clusters)
clusterExport(cl=clusters, varlist=foreachArguments, envir=environment())
results <- DEoptim(fn=myfunc1,lower=lower,upper=upper,
                DEoptim.control(itermax=itermax,trace=trace,parallelType=pType,
                parVar=parVar))
showConnections(all = TRUE)
closeAllConnections()





# foreach with foreachArgs specified: doesn't work
pType = 2               
clusters <- makeCluster(ncores, type = cltype)
registerDoParallel(clusters)
clusterExport(cl=clusters, varlist=foreachArguments, envir=environment())

results <- DEoptim(fn=myfunc1,lower=lower,upper=upper,
                DEoptim.control(itermax=itermax,trace=trace,parallelType=pType,
                foreachArgs=foreachArguments))
showConnections(all = TRUE)
closeAllConnections()





# foreach with foreachArgs unspecified: works
pType = 2               
foreachArguments <- list("myfunc1","myfunc2","loss_func","ncal","n_left_cens","astats","X_ret","disc_length",
                        "X_acq","POP_0","POP_ann_growth")
clusters <- makeCluster(ncores, type = cltype)
registerDoParallel(clusters)
clusterExport(cl=clusters, varlist=foreachArguments, envir=environment())

results <- DEoptim(fn=myfunc1,lower=lower,upper=upper,
                DEoptim.control(itermax=itermax,trace=trace,parallelType=pType))
showConnections(all = TRUE)
closeAllConnections()
```

Comment: When I run your code, your first example fails with, "Error in clusterExport(...) object 'foreachArguments' not found"; and your second example fails with, "Error in parallelArgs$.packages : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable". So you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: My apologies Josh - 'foreachArguments' was defined below when it should have been defined above. Edit made. On a fresh R session, the results are as they had been described -- works, doesn't work giving that error message, then works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `?DEoptim.control`:

> foreachArgs: A list of named arguments for the ‘foreach’ function from
>   the package ‘foreach’.  The arguments ‘i’, ‘.combine’ and ‘.export’ are
>   not possible to set here; they are set internally.

Which you seem to be conflating with the behavior of `parVar`:

> parVar: Used if ‘parallelType=1’; a list of variable names (as strings)
>   that need to exist in the environment for use by the objective function
>   or are used as arguments by the objective function.

You need to specify the arguments passed to `foreach` as `name = value` pairs. For example:

```
foreachArguments <- list(.export = c("myfunc1", "myfunc2", "loss_func", "ncal",
 "n_left_cens", "astats", "X_ret", "disc_length", "X_acq","POP_0","POP_ann_growth")
```

I'm not sure what's causing that specific error, but the fix is "don't do that." ;)

Here's an example of how you'd actually use the `foreachArgs` argument. Note that I'm setting the `.verbose` argument to make `foreach` print diagnostics:

```
library(doParallel)
library(DEoptim)
clusters <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(clusters)
obj_func <- function(params) { sum(params) }
results <- DEoptim(fn=obj_func, lower=c(-1, -1), upper=c(1, 1),
  DEoptim.control(parallelType=2, foreachArgs=list(.verbose=TRUE)))
stopCluster(clusters)
```

Comment: Thank you Josh! While foreach didn't export variables for me, your specification of foreachArguments did the trick when using foreachArgs. It provided the same results as what I obtain by exporting manually and not using foreachArgs.

Comment: @user052084: I'm not certain `foreach` automatically exports variables, so I removed that comment from my answer.  Sorry for any confusion.